# ¿Cómo pasar una variable de una página a otra archivo a través de un enlace?

Tags: php

Quiero pasar la variable `cedula` a los enlaces que están debajo de la tabla. ¿Qué puedo hacer para lograrlo?

He intentado de todo, pero no consigo hacerlo.

```
<tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>;
                <td><?php echo $row['apellido'];?></td>;
                <td><?php echo $row['cedula'];?></td>;
                <td><?php echo $row['direccion'];?></td>;
                <td><?php echo $row['telefono'];?></td>;
                <td>
                    <form method="GET" action="../../php/editarEstudiante.php">
                        <button type="submit"> Editar </button> 
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form method="GET" action="../../php/borrarEstudiante.php" >
                        <button type="submit"> Borrar </button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Agrega algo de lo que has intentado por favor

Comment: lo borre porque no sirvio, basicamente era intentar pasarla por la url o por un form con un action

Comment: Cualquier intento es bueno y nos da pie para intentar ayudarte

Comment: @BetaM listo, edite y lo que puse es lo que tenia antes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya que estás usando botones <kbd>Editar</kbd> y <kbd>Borrar</kbd> dentro de un formulario que realiza el envío mediante una petición `GET`, podrías usar un campo `<input>` invisible para almacenar y enviar dicho valor junto con el formulario o bien aprovechar esos mismos `<button>` para realizar esa misma tarea:

```
<tr>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['nombre']) ?></td>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['apellido']) ?></td>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['cedula']) ?></td>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['direccion']) ?></td>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['telefono']) ?></td>
    <td>
        <form method="GET" action="../../php/editarEstudiante.php">
            <button type="submit" name="cedula"
              value="<?= htmlspecialchars($row['cedula']) ?>"> Editar </button> 
        </form>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form method="GET" action="../../php/borrarEstudiante.php" >
            <button type="submit" name="cedula"
              value="<?= htmlspecialchars($row['cedula']) ?>"> Borrar </button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Además, te recomiendo encarecidamente que uses [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://php.net/htmlspecialchars) para que los caracteres HTML se muestren correctamente (como los símbolos `<`, `&`, etc) y, sobre todo, evitar [ataques XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, los elementos de tipo `button` admiten la etiqueta `value`, por tanto, se puede poner  el dato  en el `button` sin necesidad de un input oculto. No lo he probado, pero debería funcionar. O, se puede pasar en la URL. La  idea es no cargar el DOM con elementos innecesarios.

Comment: Así es, igual que pasa con los `<input type="submit">` :) gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Ya he hecho el cambio. Gracias, como siempre, por la sugerencia.

Answer (score 2):

Considero que puedes:

- Indicar en la URL declarada en el atributo `action` un parámetro, por ejemplo **cedula** así:

  ```
  ?cedula
  ```
- Igualar este parámetro con el valor que recuperas en la iteración de está forma:

  ```
  ?cedula=$row['cedula']
  ```

Completa dicha URL se vería así:

```
../../php/editarEstudiante.php?cedula=$row['cedula']
```

Ahora este parámetro con el valor asignado viaja al archivo destino, en este lo puedes recuperar por medio de [la superglobal `$_GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php) así:

```
$cedulaRecuperada = $_GET['cedula'];
```

Comment: Gracias, de todos modos ya lo solucione, lo agregare como una respuesta mas por si alguien lo llega a necesitar, muy amable y util tu respuesta.

Comment: Adelante, entre más conocimiento mejor

Comment: Me parece más factible esto que crear un elemento adicional.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['apellido'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['cedula'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['direccion'];?></td>                
                <td><?php echo $row['telefono'];?></td>
                <td>
                <form method="POST" 
                action="../../php/editarEstudiante.php">
                <button type="submit"> Editar <input 
                type="hidden" name="cedula" value="<?php 
                echo $row['cedula']?>"> </button> 
                </form>
                </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que consultes mi respuesta. A parte de que es casi lo mismo, hago uso de [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://php.net/htmlspecialchars) para evitar dos males: que no se muestren correctamente caracteres que se usan para definir HTML y [ataques XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Esto último es algo muy grave, a la altura de la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL), que debes evitar en tu aplicación.

Comment: @OscarGarcia gracias por el aporte

Comment: Gracias, un placer ser de ayuda :)